# Detener la impresion con PrintDocument EN VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

hola muy buenas les comento que estoy imprimiendo con print document un ticket,  el ticket lo imprime bien excepto que sigue de seguido con espacio en blanco muy extenso en la parte de abajo lo cual desperdicia mucho papel, no se si hay algun comando para que se detenga apenas termine el ticket aqui les dejo el codigo agradezco mucho su colaboración.

```
 Dim fuente As System.Drawing.Font = New Font("consolas", 15)
    Dim topMargin As Double = e.MarginBounds.Top
    Dim yPos As Double = 0
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim texto As String = ""
    Dim unidad As Byte = 0
    Dim detalle As String = ""
    Dim valor As Decimal = 0
    Dim tabulacion As String = ""
    Dim compensador As Integer = 0
    Dim total As Decimal = 0


    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    '  Dim dr As DataRow

    Dim campito As String


    campito = "id"
    Dim strsql As String = "select id,impresora,representante,establecimiento,direccion,telefono,nit,mensaje,regimen,resolucion from mi_factura where " & campito & " like '" & "" & "%" & "'"

    Dim adp As New MySqlDataAdapter(strsql, conn)

    ds.Tables.Add("mi_factura")
    adp.Fill(ds.Tables("mi_factura"))

    Dim establecimiento As String
    Dim direccion As String
    Dim telefono As String
    Dim nit As String
    Dim mensaje As String
    Dim impresora As String



    establecimiento = ds.Tables("mi_factura").Rows(0).Item("establecimiento").ToString
    direccion = ds.Tables("mi_factura").Rows(0).Item("direccion").ToString
    telefono = ds.Tables("mi_factura").Rows(0).Item("telefono").ToString
    nit = ds.Tables("mi_factura").Rows(0).Item("nit").ToString
    mensaje = ds.Tables("mi_factura").Rows(0).Item("mensaje").ToString
    impresora = ds.Tables("mi_factura").Rows(0).Item("impresora").ToString()
    representante = ds.Tables("mi_factura").Rows(0).Item("representante").ToString()


    ' Imprime la cabecera
    yPos = 40
    Dim printFont As System.Drawing.Font = New Font("consolas", 12)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(establecimiento, fuente, Brushes.Black, 80, 40)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(direccion, printFont, Brushes.Black, 80, 60)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(nit, printFont, Brushes.Black, 80, 80)
    ''  e.Graphics.DrawString("Tiket N. " & Me.Numerotiket.Text, printFont, Brushes.Black, 10, 100)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Fecha: " & Date.Now, printFont, Brushes.Black, 10, 120)
    '' e.Graphics.DrawString("Mesa N. " & NumeroMesa.Text, printFont, Brushes.Black, 10, 160)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("****************************", printFont, Brushes.Black, 10, 180)

    Dim cant As String
    Dim desc As String
    Dim imp As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim dst As New DataSet
    Dim dtp As New DataTable
    Dim camp As String

    camp = "mesa"

    'Dim adpt As New MySqlDataAdapter("select * from  tikets", conn)

    Dim adpT As New MySqlDataAdapter("select * from pedidofin where " & camp & " like '" & VENTAS.ComboBox2.Text & "'", conn)

    dst.Tables.Add("pedidofin")
    adpT.Fill(dst.Tables("pedidofin"))


    ''''''''''''''''''''''
    e.Graphics.DrawString("CNT       ITEM          IMPO ", printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 10, 200)
    For i = 1 To adpT.Fill(dst.Tables("pedidofin"))
        Cant = dst.Tables("pedidofin").Rows(i).Item("cnt").ToString
        desc = dst.Tables("pedidofin").Rows(i).Item("item").ToString
        imp = dst.Tables("pedidofin").Rows(i).Item("precio").ToString
        ' Cant = Cant + "  "

        texto = cant & "  " & desc & "  " & imp
        yPos = 120 + topMargin + (count * printFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics)) ' Calcula la posición en la que se escribe la línea
        ' Imprime la línea con el objeto Graphics

        e.Graphics.DrawString(texto, printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 10, yPos)
        total += valor

        count += 1

    Next



    yPos += 10
    e.Graphics.DrawString("____________________________", printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 10, yPos)
    Dim tot As Integer = 0
    tot = Len(TextBox1.Text)
    '' lineaTotal = StrDup(28 - XXX, ".")
    yPos += 20
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Total " & tot & total, printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 10, yPos)
    yPos += 30
    e.Graphics.DrawString("****************************", printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 10, yPos)
    yPos += 30
    e.Graphics.DrawString("gracias por su compra", printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 10, yPos)
    '' e.Graphics.DrawString(Me.Preferenciabindingdource.Current("Coletilla"), printFont, Brushes.Black, 10, yPos + 20)
    ''e.Graphics.DrawString("---------------------------------", printFont, Brushes.Black, 10, 180)
    '' e.Graphics.DrawString("Gracias por su compra!", printFont, Brushes.Black, 10, 180)
    e.HasMorePages = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba seteandole un tamaño fijo a la pagina puede funcionar.

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.papersize(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

```
Dim PrintDocument1 As PrintDocument = New PrintDocument()
Dim pkCustomSize1 As New PaperSize("Custom Paper Size", 100, 200)
PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = pkCustomSize1
```